# Mysqli_Query warning: expets parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this other function that i'm having problems with and this is the error i get

mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

This is my code:

```
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $sql = mysqli_query($query, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' ", 0 == 1) ? true : false;
    return ($sql);
}
```

The first parameter should be for the connection right?

Comment: Yes, first parameter is the connection.

Comment: Mysql_query only accepts 2 parameters the connection and the query,0=1 doesnt belong there

Comment: "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given" It seems, that $query isn't the mysqli connection, where you define it and how do you give it to the function (i think it's a class?!)

Comment: @TheDubleM why $link and $query? That seems to be a useless variable definition.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query requires two parameters. One is the mysqli_connect() and the other is your basic query. The error: "`mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given`" means either you are not connected to your mysql database or there is an error in your `$query = mysqli_connect()` script. Try checking your database connection using the `mysqli_error()` method.

Comment: The OP is using a variable, `$query`, that has not been initialised as the first argument to `mysqli_query`. That is why the error is appearing.